# @client.on(events.NewMessage) no longer captures all events

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm new here, so forgive me if I don't meet certain parameters for questions.

I have a problem: until a few months ago "*@client.on(events.NewMessage)*" used to capture all messages coming to me from all groups and channels, however since a few months ago only in a subset of groups and channels it triggers. Has there been some settings/privacy update that I missed?

For example: messages written in the Telethon support group are correctly captured and printed, while from other groups (e.g. amazon discounts) the function is not triggered.

Thanks to all

| SW | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Ubuntu Server | 21.04 |
| Python | 3.9.5 |
| Telethon | 1.24.0 |

Test Code:

```
from telethon import *

API_ID = 123...
API_HASH = "AAAABBBBCCCDDDD..."

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

print("START TEST")

client = TelegramClient('session_cookie', API_ID, API_HASH)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler_mex(event):
    print("Message:",event.message.message)

try:
    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()    
finally:
    client.disconnect()
    print("END TEST")
```

Comment: Try `@client.on(events.NewMessage())`, note the `()` at the end.

Comment: I've done this test before, with no results. The thing is that with some groups it works with others it doesn't, that's why I thought about some problem due to the privacy of the groups or some setting.